# I need to console.log a variable and in the same line run a function then also print the variable again

Tags: javascript, string, hex

Basically, I have a variable, `c1`, which is given a random hex value. Then, I need to print it to the console. But, then, I want to print another hex value, and I don't want to make another variable (because i'm lazy), and so instead, I want to do something like this:

```
function thing() {
  // generate random hex value code (it works)
}

console.log (variable + thing() + variable);
```

I have not found anything that could help with this, and I don't even know if what I'm trying to do is possible. If it isn't, then I will add the other variables, but I want to try with this first.

I don't even know what to try first, and so here I am!

Comment: Do you mean `console.log(variable); thing(); console.log(variable);`? You can put all your code into one line.

Comment: What's your problem? How many times do you call `console.log()`? I think only one time now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this question is weird, and we're not sure what you are after so I'm going to fill in the blanks here.  You want to invoke a function and call console.log in one line while calling a function within that console log statement.  What you wrote would technically work but probably would be illegible on the console.  My suggestion is use multi-line literals with templates like this:

```
let value = thing()
console.log( `value = ${value}
thing() = ${thing()}
value = ${value}`)
```

That'll give you a line per variable and function call making it appear as separate `console.log` calls, but you are only making a single call.

Comment: so basically, a variable that calls a function when used? i never thought of that! thank you so much!

Comment: Well if that was helpful great!  But I wouldn't describe it like that.  It's not a variable that calls a function.  I'm just saying call the function `thing()` save that output to a variable (ie value).  Then within your `console.log` statement output the saved variable, and call `thing()` function again.  It's very similar to what you wrote in your psuedo code above.